# Jquery not working for special character '<'

Tags: jquery

while we entering special character eg. `<` without having spacing, enter any character like `'<test'` in text boxes, JQuery not works for client side button event. is there any solution s to allow to fire the event, even user enter such type of word `'<test'`.

Example:

if user entered `'<xyz'` and try to click on save button. its not worked for same.

if user entered `'< xyz'` then its work properly.

(Exact scenario like, if user entered like    "

need proper solution for this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you replay, exact scenario like, if user entered like    "<test" its not worked, if user entered "< test" then its worked. we used input formcollection to access some data in Controller pages. for this scenario its not working.

Answer (score -1):

i don't understand clearly what you say,
When you input `'<test'` it will work. demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/e5PPu/97/

I think `attribute encode` maybe help you

Comment: Hi Thanks for you replay, exact scenario like, if user entered like    "<test" its not worked, if user entered "< test" then its worked. we used input formcollection to access some data in Controller pages. for this scenario its not working.